# dalvikvm-heap grow heap (frag case) while upload video android

Tags: android

I am facing problem whiel uploading the video from the 4x devices.I know that only 15 sec vedio recodring will create a 30 mb file in samsung S2 but while I am trying to upload the video on the php server first it shows the msg like 
     D/dalvikvm(7638): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 263K, 9% free 12838K/14087K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
     I/dalvikvm-heap(7638): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.481MB for 1048592-byte allocation
     D/dalvikvm(7638): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 13861K/15175K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
     D/dalvikvm(7638): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 9% free 13862K/15175K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 27ms

```
I know it is the memory managment concept and device memory dependent but I want a real solution for it as I am stuck here from quite a few days.
Below is my code to call and upload the video to server.

public void newmethod( String Imageurl ) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
    byte[] data ; 
    int bytenumber,bufferSize,bytesRead;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;
     //File sourceFile =  searchForFileInExternalStorage("video.3gp");

     Log.e("in the method the path", ""+Imageurl);

      FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(Imageurl);
      bytenumber = fileInputStream.available();
      Log.e("in the method the the size of the file is", ""+bytenumber);
     // dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
      bufferSize = Math.min(bytenumber, maxBufferSize);
      data = new byte[bufferSize];
     //ProgressDialog pr = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
    // pr.addContentView(getCurrentFocus(), null);
       // read file and write it into form...
       bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

       while (bytesRead > 0) {
       // dos.write(data, 0, bufferSize);
        bytenumber = fileInputStream.available();
         bufferSize = Math.min(bytenumber, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(data, 0, bufferSize);
        }

     // pr.show();


    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://67.52.165.116/Kakz/mobiles/uploadvideo");
    ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody( data, Imageurl);
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    reqEntity.addPart("user_video", bab);

    FormBodyPart bodyPart=new FormBodyPart("title", new StringBody(title));
    reqEntity.addPart(bodyPart);
    bodyPart=new FormBodyPart("desc", new StringBody(description));
    reqEntity.addPart(bodyPart);
    bodyPart=new FormBodyPart("source", new StringBody("android"));
    reqEntity.addPart(bodyPart); 
    postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
    final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    // FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());


    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {

    //stuff that updates ui

             BufferedReader in = null;
            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
                String line = null;

    try {
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);

            titleText.setText("");
            descriptionText.setText("");
          //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video Uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("Its too Heavy")) {
            //  pr.dismiss();
                // titleText.setText("");
                //descriptionText.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video size is too heavy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            else if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("Error")) {
            //  pr.dismiss();
                // titleText.setText("");
                //descriptionText.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error uploading video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }

            else  if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("Uploaded")) {
                //pr.dismiss();
                 //titleText.setText("");
                //descriptionText.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
         }
});

Please let me know that how I should manage the code to get it right.
Any help would be appreciated ASAP`enter code here`
```

Comment: uploading in background thread??

Comment: Unless you get spammed with it for quite a time, i wouldn't worry to much about it. You're doing a heavy action and it simply requires some memory. Your app gets it's minimal heap size from start, and has room to grow for these cases.

Comment: @Raghunandan yes I am uploading it in asyntask background.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn So is there any way to control the thing have a look in my code. Some time I am able to upload upto 20 mb but once in a while.

Comment: You do not want to use an AsyncTask for this. It will be canceled whenever your Activity gets destroyed.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn Although I have handled it as there will be progress dialog box appearing on the Activity until it will not get the response. But curious to check whether it can be the problem!! but without asyntask what can be the alternate to do the stuff

Comment: For networking you want to use a service, which is loosely coupled to the Activity. Meaning it will continue, without the Activity. Blocking your user until 20~mb has been send is a bad idea anyway. You could check out my answer here for other options; http://stackoverflow.com/a/15570732/1868384

Answer (score 1):

> I am facing problem whiel uploading the video from the 4x devices.

It's not problem. It's normal behaviour when you are doing very hight-cost operation(s). Your heap' size(implicitly determined) is in the one moment not enough so it need to be grew up. it's equal behaviour how you should write into manifest

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

this property doesn't work. When heap need more size, will grow up itself - when it's needed.
This message is usually shown when you don't have much memory.

> GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 263K, 9% free 12838K/14087K, paused 13ms, total
>   13ms I/dalvikvm-heap(7638)

Here you have only 9% memory and heap need be grew up. Usually it happens when `ALLOC` is less then 10% and doesn't not matter if you work with Thread or not, once is it a high-cost operation. And when your heap size will reach one "critical point" application will be automatic stopped for security reasons as well as VM.

One possible solution is that you need to split your file into smaller chunks and upload them one by one.

Comment: Thnx for the explanation You can see I am already sending the video in multi-part form. Is there some thing else I need to split the video in chunks how to do that??

Comment: @vyas you can split file programatically to smaller chunks when you are sending on server but on server you should merge them but now this idea is not good i think since it's video. How i meant since its large file, there is not fix for it. its only warning in logcat and if you file is uploaded successfully, there is no problem only load for CPU and RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know it is a good Idea to answer my own question. But still I feel like giving my experience for those who are facing same problem like me because after searching lot of stuff I got to know that there is no specific solution for this problem as it is device dependent and heavy memory consumption process.
Then I looked for other option like to compress the video before uploading, but I did not get any open source library for this also. So for now video uploading is not as simple as I thought in the start. :)